# Sharepoint Standard View vs Datasheet View - Records showup

Tags: datasheet, records-management

I have a weird problem.

I have created 2 views, lets say ViewA and ViewB in a list with the same criteria.

View A is a Standard View
View B is a Datasheet View

Strangely ViewA returns the records as per the criteria, but ViewB doesn't have any records showing up.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: which SharePoint version and browser you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I just found that in while creating the datasheet view, we need to select 'Show all items without folders' instead of 'show items inside folder'.

'Show items inside folder' works only if it is a Standard View.

Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score -1):

DataSheet view components might/are not installed properly.